# Explain the following JavaScript syntax: var fib = require('algorithms.js').Math.fibonacci;

Tags: javascript, syntax

I'm having trouble understanding how the following code makes sense:

```
var fib = require('algorithms.js').Math.fibonacci;
```

I see this is storing 'algorithms.js' in a var named fib but what does the '.Math.fibonacci;' mean?

Full source: https://github.com/felipernb/algorithms.js/wiki/Fibonacci

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The require function reads an external file as a JavaScript module. It's based on the module concept described in CommonJS (http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Modules/1.1) and currently implemented in a lo

In short `require()` creates provides the module as an object. `.Math.fibonacci` accesses the property `Math` and the child property `fibonacci` which itself is a function. So after all it's just a shorter way to access the function:

```
// only loads the JavaScript module
var algorithms = require('algorithms.js');
// calls the function with the fully qualified name:
algorithms.Math.fibonacci(10);

// decalare an abreviation for the function:
var fib = algorithms.Math.fibonacci;
// now you can call:
fib(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

as you can read in the [source code](https://github.com/felipernb/algorithms.js/blob/master/algorithms/math/fibonacci.js)

```
var fib = require('algorithms.js').Math.fibonacci;
```

will store in the **var fib** the `Math.fibonacci` object exported by **fibExponential** object function and defined into **algorithms.js**

I would suggest you [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/)  to understaind better how work a script loader

Comment: Do you know where I could find some more info on this approach? I'm trying to search google but not really sure what question I'm asking.

Comment: @iliketolearn just edited my answer, you have to read the source code